# In Windows 10, where is the default installation directory of the WSL2 Ubuntu distribution?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have `wsl --export`ed my previous version of Ubuntu and now want to import it with this command:

```
wsl --import <Distribution Name> <InstallLocation> <FileName>
```

I'd prefer to pick the same `<InstallLocation>` the previous version was on, but I don't know where that is.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you! Is there a good reason to use a different directory for my exported tar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd prefer to pick the same  the previous version was on, but I don't know where that is.

By default it's `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\<PackageName>`

Comment: Thank you! Is there a good reason to use a different directory for my exported tar?